# Remove data not fitting a threshold based on other variables in R

Tags: r, optimization, threshold

I am attempting to remove specific data (NEE) that was collected under poor conditions (Ustar < ths). The threshold is dependent upon the season. Currently, I am using a for loop, and I know R processes these very slowly, so I am looking for a better method. The dataframe is multi-variable and named Peaches.

DoY is Day of year, Ustar is a variable describing the conditions, and NEE is the observation which is thrown out under low Ustar values. The seasonal threshold is labeled as ths_1, 2, 3, or 4 depending upon the time of year. Bad data is labeled as -999 (due to requirements for other programs), but could be set as NA and then changed later if it makes the code more efficient.

This is for two years (Peaches13 and Peaches14), and years do not need to be the same length. Thresholds are the same for multiple years, and only season specific.

This is my current setup:

```
for (i in 1:length(Peaches13$DoY)){
  if((Peaches13$DoY[i] < 90)&&(Peaches13$Ustar[i] < ths_1)){
    Peaches13$NEE[i] <- -999
    }
  if((Peaches13$DoY[i] < 180)&&(Peaches13$DoY[i] >= 90)&&(Peaches13$Ustar[i] < ths_2)){
    Peaches13$NEE[i] <- -999
  }
  if((Peaches13$DoY[i] < 270)&&(Peaches13$DoY[i] >= 180)&&(Peaches13$Ustar[i] < ths_3)){
    Peaches13$NEE[i] <- -999
  }
  if((Peaches13$DoY[i] >= 270)&&(Peaches13$Ustar[i] < ths_4)){
    Peaches13$NEE[i] <- -999
  }
}

for (i in 1:length(Peaches14$DoY)){
  if((Peaches14$DoY[i] < 90)&&(Peaches14$Ustar[i] < ths_1)){
    Peaches14$NEE[i] <- -999
  }
  if((Peaches14$DoY[i] < 180)&&(Peaches14$DoY[i] >= 90)&&(Peaches14$Ustar[i] < ths_2)){
    Peaches14$NEE[i] <- -999
  }
  if((Peaches14$DoY[i] < 270)&&(Peaches14$DoY[i] >= 180)&&(Peaches14$Ustar[i] < ths_3)){
    Peaches14$NEE[i] <- -999
  }
  if((Peaches14$DoY[i] >= 270)&&(Peaches14$Ustar[i] < ths_4)){
    Peaches14$NEE[i] <- -999
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a for loop.  For example, you're first for loop could be replace with :

```
badValues <- with(Peaches13,
                (((DoY < 90)&(Ustar < ths_1)) | 
                ((DoY < 180)&(DoY >= 90)&(Ustar < ths_2)) | 
                ((DoY < 270)&(DoY >= 180)&(Ustar < ths_3)) | 
                ((DoY >= 270)&(Ustar < ths_4)) ) )

Peaches13$NEE[badValues] <- -999
```

which would be much faster.  You could also go the dplyr route as in:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(Peaches13, NEE = ifelse(badValues , -999, NEE))
```

Comment: The first solution will result in all NEE values becoming -999, provided any DoY is less than 90 and any Ustar < ths_1, rather than the specific observation for which the 2 conditions are met.

Comment: The second solution appears to have the same problem.

Comment: The problem (if your tried running the script) was that I forgot to change the `&&` operator (which only evaluates the first element of each vector) to the `&` operator (which operates on each element).   Other than that, this script should work.   If id doesn't work, try including some of your data in your post (i.e. `dput(head(Peaches13,10))`).